# Adding entity property with more than 500 characters/setting unindexed

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-node

I'm trying to create a entity with a property of more than 500 characters by setting the indexed value to false.

How would I go about doing this with the gcloud-node library with the save function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably noticed, the `indexed` value is `true` by default. I've opened a PR which would add support for overriding. If you have any thoughts and/or want to try it out, please post them over there :) https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/pull/218